# SqlAchemy products table join to stock table with sum

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I join these tables so I can list all the products with their summed stock count from the stock table, I also want to join the category table to the products table so I can get the category name.

```
class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stock'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stock = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    transaction_type = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    status = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Integer)
    sale_receipt_id = Column(ForeignKey('sale_receipt.id'), index=True)

    product = relationship('Product')
    sale_receipt = relationship('SaleReceipt')

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    barcode = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    sku = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    cost_price_id = Column(ForeignKey('cost_price.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    sell_price_id = Column(ForeignKey('sell_price.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    supplier_id = Column('supplier.id', ForeignKey('supplier.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    category_id = Column(ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    variant_id = Column(ForeignKey('variant.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    size_id = Column(ForeignKey('size.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    status = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    image = Column(JSON)
    reorder_threshold = Column(String(45))
    tags = Column(String(200))

    category = relationship('Category')
    company = relationship('Company')
    cost_price = relationship('CostPrice')
    sell_price = relationship('SellPrice')
    size = relationship('Size')
    supplier = relationship('Supplier')
    variant = relationship('Variant')

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    status = Column(String(45), nullable=False)

    company = relationship('Company')
```

I am able to sum the stock but I don't know how to join products to it.

```
rds_session.query(Stock.product_id, func.sum(Stock.stock).label("stockTotal")).join(Product).group_by(Stock.product_id).all()
```

this gives me list of tuple like this

```
[(<functions.database.db.Product object at 0x7f863ce650b8>, Decimal('3'))]
```

I want the summed stock and product in a single entity.
sorry for bad english let me know if something is not clear

---- SOLVED ----
I was able to do it with this query:

```
x_add = rds_sesssion.query(Stock.product_id, func.sum(func.IF(Stock.transaction_type == 'add', Stock.stock, -Stock.stock)).label('totalStock')).group_by(Stock.product_id).subquery()
results = rds_sesssion.query(Product, x_add.c.totalStock).join(x_add, Product.id == x_add.c.product_id).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got the 2-tuples with the given query above.  A solution is to put the count sum query into a subquery and join that subquery from Product.  I'm not sure what you mean by "single entity" because you still get a list of 2-tuples.  Did you want the computed property to be attached to the class ?  The category should be available on `product.category`.  You might want to use `.options(joinedload(Product.category))` on the second query to optimize loading the category.

```py
# Create query to get the count and use .subquery().
stock_subquery = rds_session.query(Stock.product_id, func.sum(Stock.stock).label("stockTotal")).group_by(Stock.product_id).subquery()

# Join Product with subquery
# note that columns in subquery are only accessible with c and
# that we use the label created above.
# This should return a list of 2-tuples of the for:
# [(Product, stockTotal)...]
results = rds_session.query(Product, stock_subquery.c.stockTotal).join(stock_subquery, Product.id == stock_subquery.c.product_id).all()

for product, stock_total in results:
    print (product, product.category, stock_total)
```

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply...
your solution look great!. but there is one more thing. I want to add, subtract based on another column value.
for example i have if I have 4 columns for Stock table like
id, product_id, quantity, operation.

operations column can have 2 values, either REMOVE or ADD.
I want to STOCK columns to be added where OPERATION column is ADD, and STOCK column to be subtracted where OPERATION column is REMOVE. Then join products. makes sense?

Comment: your answered helped alot and i was able to modify your answer to get what i wanted.Thanks I'm accepting it as right answer! I added the solution to the question